# How to style one half of a Highchart one way and the other another?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, trading

I'm building a depth chart for a trading system.  [image: Example]:

We're using Highcharts.  There are two approaches: stack two charts next to one another and have separate data, or load the bid and ask data into one list and create the chart that way.

Is one way of preparing the data better?

**Will I be able to color half green and the other half red** if I combine the data?

Comment: If you have two series of data then specify a color for each of them - http://jsfiddle.net/jx1vb0fp/. If you have one series of data, use zones option to color a specific part of the graph http://jsfiddle.net/jx1vb0fp/2/

Answer (score 1):

I assume the data would be an array of x,y points... 
If so, you could find the array index directly in the middle like this...

```
//This rounding should be verified,
//this is off the top of my head
var midNum = Math.ceil( ( data.length / 2 ) );
```

Use `midNum` to change the styling on the points that are the middle point and beyond. Like this...

```
//should also be checked
.point-selector:nth-child(n+(midNum))
```

Check out [this site](http://www.nthmaster.com) for more on nth- selectors, I have always found it helpful.

That selector can be used in plain js or jQuery to select elements for .style or .css() respectively